# Converting column numbers to hour in MATLAB

Tags: string, matlab, datetime, number-formatting

I have a column with 24 values from `00, 01, 02, .... , 23`.

What's the best way in MATLAB to convert to `00:00, 01:00, 02:00, 03:00 ... 23:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
vals = cellstr(num2str((0:23)','%02d'));
vals = strcat(vals, ':00');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>> t = (0 : 23) / 24;
>> s = datestr(t, 'HH:MM');
```